# 1Password & Wine on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, firefox, wine

When I run 1Password (Windows version) using Wine on Linux Mint, should the belonging browser add-on running natively in Firefox work, or must the browser also run in Wine? Is there any settings or tweaks I need to do? I can't get the browser add-on to connect with the 1Password main program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2018-06-24**

**The solution described below will stop working** at some point, because it assumes agilebits still use a websocket protocol, and they are progressively moving away form this tecnology due to problems they encoutered, instead they are moving all platforms to what they call *native messaging*.

At this time only the chrome extension (maybe the opera one too) is still using websocket. However this won't last forever. For example the below technique don't work with firefox, my attempts to hack this around with firefox, wine and 1password 4.x didn't worked.

*See [this thread](https://discussions.agilebits.com/discussion/84043/firefox-57-and-1password4-running-on-linux-requires-net-4-6-1-or-later-support) for more information.*

---

This solution is for people who **do not have the AgileBits online account** (as in remote vault) and that still want to have *offline* vaults (as in synchronize yourself).

For users who have **online accounts**, AgileBits have new beta software that can access the online vault either within [Chrome](https://blog.agilebits.com/2017/11/13/1password-x-a-look-at-the-future-of-1password-in-the-browser/) or with the [command line](https://blog.agilebits.com/2017/09/06/announcing-the-1password-command-line-tool-public-beta/).

**Edited**

---

I wrote myself a guide to install 1Password on Linux with **wine**. And that auto start with **systemd**. Note however that guide has been tested on the great *archlinux*, other distros may differ in various ways so instructions may need some adaptation.

### Overview

- Install Wine
- Download 1Password *4.x*
- Install 1Password in Wine
- Run 1Password
- Integrate with a browser

  - Manually starting the agent
  - Automatically at login via systemd
  - Disable browser code signature in 1Password
  - Download the extension

### Install WINE

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

### Download 1Password

Running 1Password on Linux requires the Windows version. It can grabbed at the [AgileBits Downloads page](https://agilebits.com/onepassword/windows).

### Install 1Password in Wine

Use Wine to install 1Password by entering this command:

```
wine 1Password-4.1.0.530.exe
```

This will install 1Password in your Wine directory and start the 1Password Windows installer.

Select the default install location : `C:\Program Files (x86)\1Password 4` it will be installed to the Wine folder in your home directory.

Next you'll be given the opportunity to create a Start Menu shortcut. Since you are on Linux, there is not really a start menu in the Windows way.

- **Check** the checkbox for *Don’t create a Start Menu folder*.
- **Check** the checkbox for *Create a desktop icon* if you want one and click the *Next* button.

### Run 1Password

The simplest way to run 1Password is to use the Desktop icon. If you chose to install a Desktop icon keep in mind that it will probably not show up until after a reboot of the system.

If you didn’t install a Desktop icon, you can start Dropbox with the command line.

Assuming you chose the default directory when installing 1Password, run it with:

```
~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/1Password\ 4/1Password.exe
```

### Integration with a browser

#### Manually (almost) run both

To run 1Password on Ubuntu 14.04, install Wine via apt-get. **You must start both** `1Password.exe` and `Agile1Agent.exe` to get connection to the browser. Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Starting 1Password..."

wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/1Password\ 4/1Password.exe >> /tmp/1pwd-wine.txt 2>&1 &
wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/1Password\ 4/Agile1pAgent.exe >> /tmp/1pwd-wine.txt 2>&1 &

tail /tmp/1pwd.txt
echo "Started..."
```

#### Using systemd

Even better run 1Password agent with systemd when logging in.
We need to create a user systemd unit, let's call it `1Password.agent.service` in the user systemd config folder.

```
vi $HOME/.comfig/systemd/user/1Password.agent.service
```

Paste the following content (the value of the `DISPLAY` var may change, I have seen that setups with both wayland and Xorg may need a different value eg : `:1`)

```
[Unit]
Description=1Password agent
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/wine ".wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/1Password 4/Agile1pAgent.exe"
Restart=always
Environment=DISPLAY=:0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Edit it later with systemd command `systemctl`

```
systemctl --user edit --full 1Password.agent.service
```

You may have to enable / start the systemd service.

#### Last thing

Then in 1Password, disable *"Verify web browser code signature"* via

```
Help -> Advanced -> Verify web browser code signature
```

#### Browser extension

You have to download and install the [Browser-Add On/extension from AgileBits](https://agilebits.com/onepassword/extensions). Restart your browser and it should work.

And there you have it... running 1Password across OS X and Linux.

## Old answer

---

Actually I got it working thanks to this [blog](http://blog.goodstuff.im/1password). The interesting bit is :

> To run 1Password on Ubuntu 14.04, install Wine via `apt-get`. You must start **both** `1Password.exe` and `Agile1Agent.exe` to get connection to the browser. Here's my script:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> echo "Starting 1Password..."
> wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/1Password\ 4/1Password.exe >> /tmp/1pwd.txt 2>&1 &
> wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/1Password\ 4/Agile1pAgent.exe >> /tmp/1pwd.txt 2>&1 &
> tail /tmp/1pwd.txt
> echo "Started..."
> ```
>
> Finally, in 1Password, disable **Verify web browser code signature** via `Help -> Advanced -> Verify` web browser code signature

Of course this script has to be `chmod`ed as an executable. Paths may vary depending on your install.

After I installed the browser extension, it worked as expected on all those Firefox / Opera and Chrome.